# MVC Ajax not working. Instead of same page, action open in new page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working with MVC 5. Ajax coding was not working for me. The following is my coding. Any thing I want to add

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateForm", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "textEntered" }))
        {
            @Html.TextBox("textBox1", "Enter text");
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br />
            <span id="textEntered">Nothing Entered</span>                              
        }
})
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

</body>
</html>
```

**Action**

```
    public string UpdateForm(string textBox1)
    {
        if (textBox1 != "Enter text")
        {
            return "You entered: \"" + textBox1.ToString() + "\" at " +
                DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }

        return String.Empty;
    }
```

When I click the submit button. Its redirect to new page. But in the same page I want to display the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if property `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` is set to `false` in my `web.config` file. If yes change it to `true`.

Else check

`jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` is imported on your page

[FOR MORE](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/11/17/mvc-3-ajax-redirecting-instead-of-updating-div.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the `id` of the `Html.TextBox`. The first parameter of the `TextBox` helper sets the value of the `name` attribute and not that of the `id`. Therefore you need to specifically tell the helper which Html attributes to set for your `TextBox`:

```
@Html.TextBox("textBox1", 
              "Enter text", 
              new Dictionary<string, object>(){ {"id", "textBox1"} });
```